# Issue with execute trigger on custom button > Apexchat

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have written a trigger for a custom button click open chat window; I want this trigger to be executed when clicked on a custom button in a Case object.

I am using Apexchat. My code is,

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="live-chat">Live Chat</a>
   jQuery(window).load(function() {
            jQuery('.live-chat').on('click', function() {
                jQuery('#apexchat_prechat_chat_icon').trigger("click");
            });
   });
```

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Hi @Rajan Gupta, can you please share the ref URL of apex chat? If not possible, then confirm, this chat window gets opened into the iframe or not..

Comment: Yes it generated i frame.

Answer (score 2):

As per my understanding, you're using apexchat js plugin, which gets loaded once the UI rendered properly. Hence you'll have to first get the iframe button instance then bind the that within your click scope. Hope the following code may help:

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
  jQuery('.live-chat').on('click', function() {
    //find iframe
    let iframe = jQuery('iframe#apexchat_chat_frame');

    //find button inside iframe
    let button = iframe.contents().find('#apexchat_chat_icon');

    //trigger button click
    button.trigger("click", function() {
      console.log("chat button/link clicked");
    });
  });
});
```

**Note:** I'm considering here the id of iframe is "apexchat_chat_frame" and "apexchat_chat_icon" is the id of the button or link upon click on which, the chat window gets loaded.